# Error copying FBO to VBO

Tags: opengl, vbo, fbo

After doing some computation on the GPU I want to copy the results stored in the FBO to VBOs for rendering.

*The problem*: It looks like some of the data is corrupted when I do the copy. I've already checked both buffers' format and size, and also checked that the data stored in the FBO is correct.

Consider the following code that initializes the FBO:

```
unsigned int verticesTextureId = AllocateTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, mVBOSize, 1, GL_RGBA32F, GL_RGBA);
CHECK_FOR_OPENGL_ERRORS();

unsigned int normalsTextureId = AllocateTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, mVBOSize, 1, GL_RGBA32F, GL_RGBA);
CHECK_FOR_OPENGL_ERRORS();

SetUpViewport(mVBOSize, 1);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFBOId);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, verticesTextureId, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, normalsTextureId, 0);
```

And the following code that initializes the VBOs and copies data from the FBO to the VBOs:

```
mVerticesBufferId = AllocateVBO();
CHECK_FOR_OPENGL_ERRORS();

glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, mVerticesBufferId);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, mVBOSize * 4 * sizeof(float), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

mNormalsBufferId = AllocateVBO();
CHECK_FOR_OPENGL_ERRORS();

glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, mNormalsBufferId);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, mVBOSize * 4 * sizeof(float), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, mVerticesBufferId);
glReadPixels(0, 0, mVBOSize, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);

glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, mNormalsBufferId);
glReadPixels(0, 0, mVBOSize, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
```

Here I bind the VBOs as vertex/normal attributes and call the draw:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVerticesBufferId);
glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 4 * sizeof(float), 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mNormalsBufferId);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 4 * sizeof(float), 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, mVBOSize);

glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

After this call, most points appear correctly on screen, but some appear strangely out of place. This seems to be unrelated to signal or clamping because vertices with negative or greater than 1 components are being displayed correctly.

I'm attaching pictures of a *kosh snowflake* (a curve) that's not being correctly rendered.

1) Vertices rendered as points:

[image: Kosh Snowflake (with wrong vertices rounded with red circles)]

2) Vertices rendered as line strips, using a simple geometry shader:

[image: Kosh Snowflake (wrong vertices circled in red)]

Reference Image:

[image: Correct Kosh Snowflake]

Comment: Nomencalture note: ["Buffer object"](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object) is the general term for what you keep calling a VBO. A vertex buffer object is a particular *use* of a buffer object. A pixel buffer object represents another *use* of a buffer object. The buffer object doesn't change; it is only how you use it.

Comment: "*After doing some computation in GPU I wan't to copy the results stored in the FBO to VBOs, for further geometry shader manipulation.*" Have you considered transform feedback instead? It's much simpler than rendering, then copying to a buffer, then rendering again.

Comment: Oh, and if you're recreating the buffer's storage *every frame*, then the buffer isn't `GL_STATIC_DRAW`. It's `GL_STREAM_DRAW`. Actually, it's `GL_STREAM_COPY`, since you're never writing to it or reading from it from OpenGL.

Comment: @NicolBolas About the nomenclature, thanks for the tip! By the way, why am I doing it wrong by calling my "buffers objects" VBOs? Since I'm using them to store vertices positions and normals I thought it'd be correct to call them VBOs.

Comment: @NicolBolas Currently I'm doing GPU computation on fragment shaders. If I was to use transform feedback wouldn't I need to perform them on vertex or geometry shaders instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using gDEBugger I found that the data on my VBOs were also correct. The problem was that after fragment shader computation, the homogeneous component of my vectors (the w) had garbage on them, which produced unwanted effects on transforms.